# Determine ModuleName of loaded target

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

I was wondering how do you determine the `ModuleName` of the file you've just loaded in ghc using the API.

If you look at the [Documentation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/As_a_library) of the API they always assume you know the module name before you load the file in.

I have tried top sorting the dependency graph and picking the last module there, but that doesn't seem to always return the file that was loaded in.

The way I have been able to do it previously was to modify the GHC source code to store this information in the `HscEnv`.

It would be nice if the call to `load` would return it, But there surely must be a way to do it already since GHCi knows this when it loads a file.

Comment: Perhaps a new function is needed ```loadTargetSet``` which returns ```m (Maybe [ModuleName])``` where the position of each corresponds to what's returned from ```getTargets```.

Answer (score 1):

The `haskell-src-exts` package has a [parseFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.13.3/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts.html#v%3aparseFile) function with type `parseFile :: FilePath -> IO (ParseResult Module)`. The `Module` type has a field for the module's name.

Comment: That's quite an overhead I would imagine. Having to parse the module twice, since I still need ghc to parse, desugar and typecheck. This is also done quite often. I could dig around and see how ghci does it, but I figured someone must know. :/ the last time I looked at it was for ghc 7.0.1, I would imagine the compilation pipeline looks quite different now...